# ATI driver installation failed

Tags: drivers, 13.04, ati, graphics

I tried to install the driver for my ATI Radeon HD 4330 graphics card from the AMD website. I have Ubuntu 13.04 on my HP laptop. After reboot I don't have the launcher and the borders of the windows. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Go to TTY console (Ctrl+Alt+F1) and after login write "sudo apt-get autoremove fglrx --purge" and then "unity --reset" and "sudo reboot". After reboot, things should start working and try reinstalling the driver or installing another driver. If after installing the next step of drivers gives the same error, repeat the process of the TTY console.